# using serializer inside concern rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, serialization, activesupport-concern

I am using serializer to format json response of my rails-api projector.
I am using a concern to format final response.
My code snippets are as follows

**entry_controller.rb**

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  include Response

  def index
    @entries = @current_user.entries
    json_response(@entries)
  end
end
```

**concerns/response.rb**

```
module Response
  def json_response(response, error = nil, message = 'Success', code = 200)
    render json: {
        code: code,
        message: message,
        error: error,
        response: response
    }
  end
end
```

**application_serializer.rb**

```
class ApplicationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
end
```

**entry_serializer.rb**

```
class EntrySerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :title, :content, :is_encrypted, :entry_date
end
```

In ***entries#index*** if i use ***json_response(@entries)*** my final response of request is not formatted and each entry is as in database. instead if i use `render json: @entries`. Im getting as per serializer. I want to use concern method `json_response(@entries)` along with serializers. Can someone suggest a way to use serializers in concern methods in a generic way as multiple controllers use same concern method.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use the responders gem if you want to dry up boilerplate. I can't really see anything redeeming in this code. You're just adding an additional layer of abstraction that gives you nothing.

Comment: responder gem will essentially do same this as method i defined above in concern. Instead i want to something generic.All serializers im defining are model specific if somehow i can make it work from method i defined above i don't have to worry about model instance im sending response

Answer (score 0):

Something related to serializer params is what you want to customise your response.

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
      include Response

      def index
        @entries = @current_user.entries
        render json: @entries, serializer_params: { error: nil, message: "Success", code: 200}
      end
    end

class EntrySerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :title, :content, :is_encrypted, :entry_date
  params :error, :message, :code

  def attributes
    super.merge(:error, :message, :code)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure I fully understand your question, but I don’t believe `render :json` calls `to_json` recursively if it is given a hash, like in this case.  So you may be looking for something like this in your concern:

```
  module Response
    def json_response(response, error = nil, message = 'Success', code = 200)
      render json: {
        code: code,
        message: message,
        error: error,
        response: response.to_json
      }
    end
  end
```

Comment: to_json stringifying json. instead i want json. I tried using as_json. but its not calling serializer as i wanted it to.